# Percentage change to plot in histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, error-handling

I am trying to plot histogram of percentage change in stock
my code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_csv("M:/Trading/1.JOZO/ALXN.csv")
dataframe = (data['Adj Close'])
zmena1 = (dataframe.pct_change(periods = 1)*100)
data["Zmena"] = zmena1
plt.hist(zmena1, bins = "auto", range = "auto" )
plt.show
```

but i get an error:

```
 mn, mx = [mi + 0.0 for mi in range]

TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

I tried `str(zmena1)` but can to get it... 
Do not know how to move through this one...

Comment: Please include a sample of your data to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the name of the csv file, I can guess that your data can be retrieved from Yahoo finance, so using the [Remote Access datareader](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html) I'm downloading all 2016 data to play with:

```
import datetime
data = web.DataReader('ALXN', data_source='yahoo', 
                      start=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1))
```

Now I can calculate the percent change in the `[0,100]` range

```
data['Zmena'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change(periods=1)*100
```

From there, I would definitely use the built-in [`DataFrame.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) function:

```
data['Zmena'].hist()
```

[image: Histogram]

---

**Using plt.hist**

In case you do want to use [plt.hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) instead, you need to filter out the `NaN`(not a number), in particular you will always have one as the first entry:

```
print(data[['Adj Close','Zmena']].head())

             Adj Close     Zmena
Date                            
2016-01-04  184.679993       NaN
2016-01-05  184.899994  0.119126
2016-01-06  184.070007 -0.448884
2016-01-07  174.369995 -5.269741
2016-01-08  168.130005 -3.578592
```

So, in order to use plt.hist:

```
plt.hist(data.Zmena.dropna())
```

Another problem is that you're specifying `bins = "auto", range = "auto"`, when really you should just not pass them if you want to default. See the documentation for both parameters at [pyplot.hist](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)

Comment: this is it sir.... somehow as a newbie forgot about this built in function... very thank you